# Matrix associated with a linear map w.r.t. direct sum decompositions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules

Let $E,F$ be two $A$-modules and $u\in\text{Hom}_A(E,F)$. Let $E,F$ be the direct sums of the submodules $(E_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(F_k)_{k\in K}$ respectively. Let $\phi:\bigoplus_{i\in I}E_i\rightarrow E$ and $\psi:F\rightarrow\bigoplus_{k\in K} F_k$ be the isomorphisms. For $(k,i)\in K\times I$, let $\iota_i:E_i\rightarrow\bigoplus_{i\in I}E_i$ be the canonical injection and $pr_k:\bigoplus_{k\in K}F_k\rightarrow F_k$ the canonical surjection; write $u_{ki}:=pr_k\circ\psi\circ u\circ\phi\circ\iota_i$.

We say that the matrix $M(u):=(u_{ki})_{(k,i)\in K\times I}$ is **the matrix of $u$ w.r.t. the decompositions $(E_i)_i$ and $(F_k)_k$ of $E$ and $F$ as direct sums**. The author claims that $M(u)\in\bigoplus_{k,i}\text{Hom}_A(E_i,F_k)$ but I don't see why this follows... Is this a typo?

**Edit**: $E$ and $F$ are not necessarily finite.

Comment: Are the indices sets $I$ and $J$ finite?

Comment: @Bernard No there are no assumptions on the cardinality of $I$ and $K$.

Comment: Well, you can see an element of $\bigoplus_{k,i}\operatorname{Hom}_A(E_i, F_k)$ as an infinite matrix; with  rows indexed by $K$ and  columns indexed by $I$, which multiplies a column vector with rows indexed by $I$, and  only a finite number of components $\ne 0$, so the product of this infinite matrix by the column vector makes sense.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, yes I can see that now. But shouldn't $(u_{ki})_{k,i}$ be an element of $\prod_{k,i}\text{Hom}_A(E_i,F_k)$ instead of $\bigoplus_{k,i}\text{Hom}_A(E_i,F_k)$, since $I,K$ are not necessarily finite?–Or does it follow that $(u_{ki})_{ki}$ has only a finite number of nonzero components?

Comment: It needs to have a finite numbers of rows, since the image of a vector in $\bigoplus_{i\in I}E_i$  has an image in $\bigoplus_{k\in K}F_k$.